# Django multi-model update in Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I select multiple items from an admin view and create a custom action?

Scenario: We need to select a set of books and assign set of categories (from a list) and assign them to them.

Is it possible to achieve this in Django Admin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing a custom view and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

already included in django: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: Hi, thx for the info. With the custom action, I can select a list of items and call a certain method. But I want the tags to be selected by the user, i.e. I need a user selection box dynamically populated.